# Maintaining Javascript Code highlighting inside @section tag with Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, knockout.js

I've joined a new dev team. They have javascript & knockout inside a `@section {}` declaration in their razor views. The javascript has no color highlighting at all, how can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, whilst doing development you could encapsulate the js with <script> tags so that VS recognizes it as JavaScript and puts the colour formatting in and then when you're done remove the script tags again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can really do there.
My suggestion would be to get rid of the javascript inside your views, and move them to external JS-files.

Of course, you could (and should) do this gradually. A good approach would be to move a script every time you need to edit it. That way you always benefit from highlighting but don't need to spend a lot of time upfront on refactoring. You'll end up with a cleaner solution as well.